# How to get a Terraform element's name (e.g. name of a local or a variable)?

Tags: terraform

I have this Terraform code:

```
locals {
    environment_variables = {
        db_connection_string = ""
    }
}
```

And I am generating the following code (code's language irrelevant):

```
resource local_file configuration_strings {
    content = <<EOT

    public class Config {
        /* ... stuff ... */
        public string ConnectionString => configProvider["db_connection_string"];
        /* ... things
    }

EOT
}
```

Is there a way to let Terraform provide the **name** of the field (`"db_connection_string"`), rather than its value (`""`), in case e.g. I ever rename it and forget to update? for instance something like:

```
public string ConnectionString =>
    configProvider[get_name_of(local.environment_variables.db_connection_string)];
```

which should emit e.g.:

```
public string ConnectionString =>
    configProvider["db_connection_string")];
```

(again: emit `configProvider["db_connection_string")]`, not `configProvider["")]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [matchkeys](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/matchkeys) to look up the key based on the value:

```
matchkeys(keys(local.environment_variables),values(local.environment_variables),[""])[0]
"db_connection_string"
```